# Fab isnt aligning properly

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager

I'm using a view pager. I'm having an issue with aligning the fab to the `bottom|end`of the screen.

My code for the view is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:text="Words" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and it produces the following output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kj83o.png)

It gets cropped down.
I think that it might be rendering the screen size for the fragment and ignoring the actual view of the activity that i called it from.

Any one have any thoughts on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: maybe it is the margin

Comment: If the margin gets removed then the fab sinks lower.